# How to make changes to httpd.conf of apache running inside DOCKER container and restart apache

Tags: apache, docker, save, httpd.conf

I am new to docker. In our docker environment - Apache has been installed and it is up and running.
Now I need to get into the container, modify the `httpd.conf`, save it and then I need to restart the apache.

Can you guys please let me know, what needs to be done.
I am pretty much confused about -
'exec' and 'attach' commands.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No need to attach or exec (which is really a debug feature anyway)

You can use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy a local version of your `httpd.conf` to the container. (That way, you can modify the file from the comfort of your local environment)

```
docker cp httpd.conf <yourcontainer_name>:/path/to/httpd.conf
```

Once that is done, you can send an USR1 signal to ask for a graceful restart (see [`docker kill`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/) syntax):

```
docker kill --signal="USR1" <yourcontainer_name>
```

Replace `<yourcontainer_name>` by the container id or name which is running Apache.

That will only work if the main  process launched by your container is

```
CMD ["apachectl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

See more at "[Docker: How to restart a service running in Docker Container](https://kuldeeparya.wordpress.com/2015/01/17/docker-how-to-restart-a-service-running-in-docker-container/)"

Comment: Thanks VonC,

But this docker containers are built and configured by the third party for us.

So still checking on where the Dockerfile is and what all the commands has been added in it.

Can you please let me know on how to check the same:
CMD [“apachectl”, “-DFOREGROUND”] has been added or not?

Also what exactly the USR1 will do?, should we run this command outside the container?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @SunagSunagms very simple: do a `docker inspect <yourContainer_name>|grep CMD`

Comment: @SunagSunagms as for USR1, that is explained in https://kuldeeparya.wordpress.com/2015/01/17/docker-how-to-restart-a-service-running-in-docker-container/, the last link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much VonC !! ,,, Let me go through the article .
If any more info needed i will let you know!!.

Comment: Hi VonC,
Thanks - CMD gave the info that cmd : /run-httpd.sh 

The file had the following content :

#!/bin/bash

exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND

This means i can use USR1 command to restart the apache gracefully, right?

Thanks!

Comment: @SunagSunagms then try the same inspect command, but using the image from which the container is run (a docker inspect of the container should at least give you the image, and inspecting the image should give you the CMD)

Comment: @SunagSunagms yes, `USR1` should trigger a graceful restart, since the main process is `/usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND`.

Comment: Getting error:  
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container –signal=USR1: No such container: –signal=USR1

Comment: By the way, while command failes, it stopped container rudely. I.e. current HTTP request was abandoned in the middle. Bad solution!

Comment: @Sergey it stops because the option was not recognized: again, I have fixed the typo (missing '-'), and a graceful restart will be send. "Graceful", as in stop when no http activity is being processed.

Comment: Remember to use sudo if you run with sudo at first time.

Answer (score 4):

To update Apache configs you need to:

1. Replace Apache configs.

   - If you have config folder mapped from outside of container you should update configs outside of container.
   - If your apache configs are stored inside of container, you will need to run something like this:

     ```
     docker cp httpd.conf YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME:/path/to/httpd.conf
     ```
2. Do **Graceful Apache restart**:

   ```
   sudo docker exec -it YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME apachectl graceful
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Enter a container by opening a bash shell:

```
docker exec -it containerName bash
```

I guess you better just reload apache config and not reboot apache.
But I wouldn't go this route and just modify Dockerfile and rebuild and rerun the image.

edit for link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: 1)Thanks  a lot for quick reply,I can make changes inside container to httpd.conf, But when  try to reload the apache config as -
'service httpd reload'
It is showing the bash: command is not available. Please let me know how to reload apache config inside container.

2)Also , can you please let me know how to find the path to Docker file and ADD the lines to make changes in httpd.conf save it and rebuild and rerun the image?